# Cannot find module './components/login/authenticationcallbackactivateguard'

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm having issues trying to import my injectible service into a Component. Try as I might I can't get the system to see AuthenticationCallbackActivateGuard.

I'm using a modified version of [Steve Sanderson's ASP.Net Core based Angular 2 template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/). It imports perfectly fine in app.module but as soon as I try pull it through on my Login component it can't find it anymore.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { AuthenticationCallbackActivateGuard } from './components/login/authenticationcallbackactivateguard';


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, AuthenticationCallbackActivateGuard ],
    declarations: [

        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        AuthenticationCallbackActivateGuard,
        LoginComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationCallbackActivateGuard] },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: '#', component: LoginComponent},
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'signin-auth0', component:HomeComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired, JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { AuthCallback } from './components/login/authenticationcallbackactivateguard'; //<-- Error is here

let Auth0Lock = require('auth0-lock').default;


let options = {
    auth: {
        redirect: true,
        rememberLastLogin: true
    },
    languageDictionary: {
        title: "Login"
    },
 theme: {
     logo: 'http://www.sapientsoft.co.za/img/sapient-logo.png',
     primaryColor: '#2E5EAC',

  } 
};  


@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    template: require('./login.component.html'),
    providers: []
})  
//providers: [Auth]
export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(authCallback: AuthCallback)
    {

    }

    lock = new Auth0Lock('WnB39V8Rwss366sATm01HbVcWijm96Vd', 'sapientfranko.eu.auth0.com',options);
    jwtHelper : JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();


    login()
    {


        this.lock.show("authenticated", (authResult) => {
            localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(authResult.profile));
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

            console.log(
                this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(authResult.id_token),
                this.jwtHelper.getTokenExpirationDate(authResult.id_token),
                this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(authResult.id_token)
            );
            this.loggedIn();  

        });


    }

    logOut()
    {
        localStorage.removeItem('profile');
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');

        this.loggedIn();
    }


    loggedIn()
    {
        return tokenNotExpired();
    }

}
```

**AuthenticationCallbackActivateGuard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationCallbackActivateGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private location: Location) { }

    canActivate() {
        // You may want to make a more robust check here
        return this.location.path(true).indexOf("access_token") === -1;
    }
}
```

**My folder structure**

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZv1Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you shouldn't bootstrap your guard. You actually add it to your providers in ngModule, that way the guard and other providers like services are available in the whole app.

```
providers: [AuthenticationCallbackActivateGuard]
```

.. and if you do that, you do not need to add it any of your components. If you want to implement it in your login-component you just add it to your routing-module, the same way you have marked it in your home-component in the routing

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate[AuthenticationCallbackActivateGuard] },
```

As to your error, the reason is simply that you try to import it with the wrong name, in the login-component you try to import it like:

```
import { AuthCallback } from './components/login/authenticationcallbackactivateguard'; //<-- Error is here
```

even though the name of the component seems to be: `AuthenticationCallbackActivateGuard`

If you do not want to add the provider in your module, you can also just add the provider in each component, but I find it better and easier to just declare it in the module, so you do not need to make sure that you have it imported in every component where you need it :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it went

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks